# Ridge and Quadratic Programming for Portfolio Norm Optimization

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, minimum-variance

Much like this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119795/quadratic-programming-and-lasso, I'm trying to integrate RIDGE Penalty in a dedicated quadratic solver. In my case, I am working with *quadprog* from MATLAB. Unlike LASSO where you can eliminate the absolute value in the constrained form and rewrite them in linear form (effectively keeping a quadratic problem), you can't with RIDGE. This means that in order to have a quadratic problem, I have to work with the penalty form:

$$ RIDGE: \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y - x'\beta)^2 + \lambda \sum \beta_{i}^{2}$$

My explicit problem is to minimize the variance with added RIDGE Penalty.

$${\underset{w}{\arg\min}} \frac{1}{2} w' \Sigma w \ + \lambda \sum w_i^{2}$$
$$s.t. \ \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i = 1$$

Basically, I want to minimize the variance while summing the weights to 1. A pretty standard problem in finance. My question is: How to adapt the objective function so that it includes the penalty? When working with a dedicated solver like *quadprog*, you can only specify the positive definite squared matrix and the vector for the unsquared terms. With the formulation below, you then specify $H$ and $f$. Link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html

$${\underset{x}{\arg\min}} \frac{1}{2} x' H x \ + f'x$$

I can either modify H (which is my covariance matrix), but this would change the number of values in my $w$ vector, or I could work with $f'$, but this is for unsquared term. I need to implement $\lambda x'x$ in my objective function, which is equal to $\lambda \sum x_i^{2}$.

Comment: Hi, shouldn’t you be simply adding \lambda times the unit matrix to our covariant matrix \Sigma ?

Comment: This question was cross-posted from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490876/ridge-and-quadratic-programming-for-portfolio-norm-optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model you were assigned comes from the following paper:

- [de Miguel et al (2009)](http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/DeMiguelGarlappiNogalesUppalMS.pdf) A Generalized Approach to Portfolio Optimization: Improving Performance by Constraining Portfolio Norms

Instead of using an additive penalty term, the ridge shrinkage of the portfolio weight vector should, or works best, as a separate constraint:

$${\underset{w}{\arg\min}} \frac{1}{2} w' \Sigma w \ $$

\begin{aligned}
s.t. & \sum w_i^{2} \leq \delta^2 \\
& \ \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i = 1
\end{aligned}

where $\delta$ has a one-to-one inverse correspondence to $\lambda$. In other words, instead of increasing $\lambda$ to make the portfolio weights smaller, you decrease $\delta$ to achieve the same regularization effect.

This is what is meant by adapting the objective function for the penalty. The linear regression formula first shown is better suited to the **Lagrangean approach** to regularization, whereas the optimization (second) formula you showed is better suited to the **constrained optimization approach** of regularization, and also deflects concerns of non-linear optimization since the main objective function (portfolio variance) I wrote is quadratic as is, while the two constraints are linear. Both approaches are equivalent due to the one-to-one correspondence between $\lambda$ and $\delta$.

If you insist on using the additive $\lambda$ penalty term, then the objective would reduce to the well-known closed-form analytical solution for the **ridge covariance matrix** where $I$ is an identity matrix the size of $\Sigma$.

$${\underset{w}{\arg\min}} \frac{1}{2} w'(\Sigma + 2\lambda I)w$$
$$s.t. \ \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i = 1$$